# Links sometimes don't work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a webpage that uses sprites for its navigation link.  In IE7 sometimes the links are not clickable.  It works fine in IE8 and Firefox.  Anyone encountered this before?

http://blazemanifesto.com

Thanks.

**Edit**
To clarify, on my computer, everything works fine. (Vista, IE8, Firefox 3, Chrome, Safari).  I had a complaint from some users that the main nav wasn't clickable.  Honestly, I thought "user error" and didn't look much further.  Last night I saw my wife browsing the site (Vista, IE7), and noticed some times when she hovered over a link it was not clickable.  The mouse pointer did not turn into a hand, and the link itself did not turn white.  Clicking did nothing.  Some links work fine, some are sporadic, some never work.

I've never seen this before, so I decided to ask you guys.

Comment: What do you mean by "not clickable"? They're work just fine for me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sometimes'?  Like, sometimes link 1 works in IE7 and other times the same link does not work?  Or some links work and some do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IE7 doesn't like that you have assigned the background image to the container .nav and that just shines through the transparent backrounds of actual links.

When I set the background image to the links directly, they started to work just fine. I suggest you do the same.

BTW, instead of writing long lines like these:

```
.nav .vision a:link, .nav .vision a:visited { ... }
.nav .vision a:hover, .nav .vision a:focus, .nav .vision a:active { ... }
```

I would just use:

```
.nav .vision a { ... }
.nav .vision a:hover { ... }
```

The first selector targets all A elements in whatever state they are and a:hover overrides that when the cursor is over A. (I guess you don't really care about all those :focus and :active states.)

Comment: Bad advice. One should cover all link states.

Comment: Well, in general case I would agree with you, but for navigation you usually don't want to differentiate visited links. I have never cared about the :active state and :focus is something, that the user agents handle quite well with some special styling which you just have to avoid overriding.

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about IE6?  You have lots of layout/image problems there.[alt text http://ejgejg.com/test/test.jpg](http://ejgejg.com/test/test.jpg)

Comment: I care, sort of.  Does Microsoft still have a downloadable VM with IE6?

Comment: Until Aug 2009, I can still use the XP VHDs from Microsoft.  Guess I still have some work to do.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Answer (score -1):

Just use Firefox.  :)

Honestly, I think you'll need to use a strict dtd:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

See more on the [IE blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/22/712830.aspx)

Comment: Why should I choose strict over transitional? It wasn't clear from the link you sent me.